# Does a non-trivial orientable vector bundle with rank $n$ have $n$ independent sections?

Tags: vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, orientation

Why I know

- A bundle of rank $n$ is trivial iff it has $n$ linearly independent sections. We can write $B\times \mathbb R^n \rightarrow E(b,t_1,...,t_n)=\sum_i t_is_i(b)$  (where $t_i\in \mathbb R$)
- If the Stiefel–Whitney class of index $i$ is nonzero, $w_i\neq0$, then there cannot exist $(n-i+1)$ everywhere linearly independent sections of the vector bundle, where $n$ is the rank of the vector bundle.
- If the first Stiefel-Whitney class is nonzero, $w_1\ne 0$, then the vector bundle is non-orientable.

I got a conclusion that:

- If a vector bundle cannot have $n$ independent sections, then it is non-trivial.
- If a vector bundle cannot have $n$ independent sections, then it is non-orientable.
- Therefore, if a vector bundle is non-trivial, then it is non-orientable. But it is wrong.

My question:

- Where did I make the mistake?
- Does a non-trivial orientable vector bundle with rank $n$ have $n$ independent sections?

Comment: This looks fishy. I’m pretty sure there are loads of non-trivial orientable line bundles… say, the tangent bundle of almost every sphere?

Comment: @ Mindlack, thanks for the comment, I revised the description now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $w_i(E) \neq 0$, then $E$ cannot admit $n-i+1$ linearly independent sections, but the converse is not true. That is, if $E$ does not admit $n - i + 1$ linearly independent sections, we could still have $w_i(E) = 0$. For example, the bundle $TS^2 \to S^2$ does not admit a linearly independent section (i.e. a nowhere-zero section) by the Poincaré-Hopf Theorem. However, we have $w_2(TS^2) = 0$; note that $1 = n - i + 1$ for $i = 2$.

In particular, if a rank $n$ bundle $E$ does not admit $n$ linearly independent sections, we could still have $w_1(E) = 0$, i.e. $E$ need not be non-orientable.